# C# Transient Dependency Pattern

Tags: c#, dependencies

I have the following situation.
SomeClass has a dependency on IDiagram and Diagram implements that interface. The lifetime of SomeClass is the lifetime of the Application, however the lifetime a Diagram is shorter. Say it could change when a certain button is pressed.
Since I could not find anything satisfying on this problem I came up with the pattern depicted in the Diagram below.

- The Observer of the Diagram would be aware that the Diagram can change and set the correct instance when it changes.
- The Observer would implement the IDiagram interface by delegating the methods of the current Diagram instance.
- SomeFactory would create new Diagrams and RaiseChanged.
- SomeClass would not be aware of any of this.

Is enforcing this pattern a good idea, which downsides are there? Is there a better solution to this problem?

[image]

Example code with IDependency instead of IDiagram below:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var transientDependency = new TransientDependency();
        var dependencyObserver = new DependecyObserver(transientDependency);
        var dependencyFactory = new Factory(transientDependency);
        var someClass = new SomeClass(dependencyObserver);
        var someOtherClass = new SomeClass(dependencyObserver);

         // Note that someClass can only be used after the dependency has been created, because the Changed event has to be invoked
        dependencyFactory.CreateDependency();
    }

    public class DependecyObserver : IDependency
    {
        public DependecyObserver(TransientDependency transient)
        {
            transient.Changed += (s, dependency) => Dependency = dependency;
        }

        private Dependency Dependency { get; set; }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Dependency.SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    public class Factory
    {
        private TransientDependency TransientDependency { get; }

        public Factory(TransientDependency transientDependency)
        {
            TransientDependency = transientDependency;
        }

        public void CreateDependency()
        {
            TransientDependency.RaiseChanged(new Dependency());
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeClass(IDependency dependency)
        {
            dependency.SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    public class TransientDependency : TransientInstance<Dependency> { }

    public abstract class TransientInstance<T>
    {
        public EventHandler<T> Changed;

        public void RaiseChanged(T instance)
        {
            Changed?.Invoke(this, instance);
        }
    }

    public class Dependency : IDependency
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface IDependency
    {
        void SomeMethod();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what each of your classes' lifetime and usage is supposed to be, maybe I got it all wrong... If `TransientDiagram` is actually transient, your `SomeFactory` will raise an event on a different instance than `DiagramObserver` is subscribing to? Or if the `TransientDiagram` is shared between the `DiagramObserver` and `SomeFactory`, why not instead pass `DiagramObserver` to the factory and set the instance there directly without all the events?

Comment: You're right, the naming is confusing, because TransientDiagram is not transient and one instance is shared between the DiagramObserver and SomeFactory. I do dislike making setters for dependecies though (it opens a bunch of possibilities to missuse classes), that's why I choose to do this via events, since I keep all dependencies in the constructor. However, I see how it makes it easier to understand by just passing DiagramObserver to SomeFactory and set the dependency there. I added a comprehensive example of the intended usage now.